# MVC Routing vs. Authorization/Authorize Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, routes, authorization

I am writing an MVC app that has two branches to travel along right from the beginning.  On path authorizes with a PIN and I am using forms authentication to limit access to this section of the code.  However, the other path will accept an AD log in and I need stop people from move between the branches using URLs.  Should I be using a custom routing or should I create two separate authorization attributes to restrict access.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Roles to handle this with the existing [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx).  Simply put your AD-authorized users into a particular role, then in the paths that require an AD-logon set the Roles for that controller/method to require the AD role.  This would entail implementing a [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) which can seem somewhat daunting, but really isn't all that bad.  Cache the user's roles in a cookie so that you don't need to look them up every time.   The advantage here is that this will scale to additional roles as your application gets more complex.

Alternatively, you could extend the existing AuthorizeAttribute, overriding [OnAuthorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization.aspx) and use your custom version.  This attribute could check to make sure that not only is the request authorized, but that it has the proper credential type.  The credential type could be stored in the session on login and retrieved from there for authenticated users.  This is simpler to write, but doesn't scale as well.